# resizableImageWithCapInsets + [UIImage:drawInRect:] with strange line

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uikit

[Demo](https://github.com/bottotl/UIImageDrawinrectBugDemo)

I create a UIImage with resizableImageWithCapInsets

then use [UIImage:drawInRect:] draw this image to a layer. I found some strange lines
[image]

```
layer.contentsScale = 2.0;// no bug
layer.contentsScale = 2.6087;// this line will cause bug
```

If contentsScale is Int, image draw perfect.
Is that mean contentsScale (CGFloat) should be set to int?

Comment: Spent some time on this myself - no luck finding a workaround other than drawing the parts myself.